# Will Woo commerce reviews show in Google with rich snippets?

Tags: seo

I am using Woo commerce as my shopping cart but I've got a small doubt regarding SEO.

My competitor is showing rich snippets i.e. star ratings in Google because of his reviews from reviewcenter.com

I too want to build reviews for users but I am not sure whether product reviews from Woo commerce will show up in Google; but in my opinion it’s better to use product reviews on site than using a 3rd party website, but before that I need to make sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter a product URL from your site into Googles rich snippet testing tool here http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

It will tell you which rich snippets are on your page. I don't believe WooCommerce supports hReview, or hProduct out of the box. You can create custom templates and add the microdata formats around the tags on the product page and reviews then test it in Google to see that it's working.

Google's site will suggest the format to use either microdata, or some other. You can also get the formats and examples from http://schema.org/docs/gs.html

Create a folder in your template folder called woocommerce and copy the whichever templates you plan to modify from the plugin folder to this newly created folder. These templates will override WooCommerce's templates so that in the future when you update the plugin your custom templates are not overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce is compatible with microformat out of the box and we can see many informations from woocommerce in the Google Rich Snippets test tool.

But for review, we can see they are avalaible in the botoom of the list with the details of rdfa datas.
But google doesn't let the stars appear in the sample.

This is working for GD Star Rating for exemple. But I agree if Woocommerce make it works out of the box, a plugin is not needed.